# HelloFacebookSample not working as expected, making facebook app to crash

Tags: ios, integration, facebook-ios-sdk, sample

I'm using sample codes (HelloFacebookSample) from "facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.2.pkg".

When I try to post status update, it fails and shows me alert.
[image: Post Status update result]

with text "Beta Feature", "This feature is not available presently"

And at the above stage, if you lock your phone and unlock it, tada! facebook app crashes.

Side note:My device is running 6.1.2. And I dont understand when how/what/when app decides to show native sharing dialog or facebook app sharing dialog or just safari.

Comment: im unable to upload image :(

Answer (score 2):

The Share Dialog (the one you're seeing) is currently in limited beta. So you're probably hitting that scenario where the dialog is presented by the SDK but the server flags you as not being in beta when you submit the share. The native share dialog is presented by the HelloFacebookSample app if you have the latest Facebook for iOS app (6.0+).

You can check this doc for more pointers on sharing and how you can use it in your app:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/

The HelloFacebookSample app is primarily showcasing the Share Dialog.

That said, if you want to successfully run the sample for now, I suggest you temporarily modify:

```
FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:urlToShare
...
}];
```

To:

```
FBAppCall *appCall = nil;
```

In the `postStatusUpdateClick:` method. This will post a status update using the either iOS6 Share Sheet or using a Graph API call.

Comment: Thanks Abernathy, I have the latest FB App. Everything seems to work fine when my FB account is not integrated with OS. When I add FB account to OS, seems like it fails to login.

Comment: Is the HelloFacebookSample app failing when you have your iOS FB account set up. Also is this failing on a device or a simulator.

Comment: it fail on device when iOS Fb account is there. Seems like example is incomplete

Comment: What error do you see? You could also try running a different sample, ex: Scrumptious sample app and see if you get errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a beta feature.  Facebook lets you enable beta features in debug mode using:

```
   [FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesOpenGraphShareDialog];
   [FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesShareDialog];
```

But it looks like Facebook just took the share dialog out of beta:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/05/20/sharing-made-simple-for-ios-apps/